# Correct way to return boxed closure

Tags: rust

```rs
fn subscribe(&mut self, subscriber: Subscriber) -> Box<dyn FnMut() -> bool> {
            self.callbacks.insert(subscriber);

            Box::new(|| self.callbacks.remove(&subscriber))
        }
```

How do I correct the error: `returning this value requires that '1 must outlive 'static`

Is it possible to do this without lifetime annotation?

Comment: Please paste the whole error including the arrows pointing to what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subscriber` is a argument in your `subscribe` function. It goes out of scope when that function returns - that is, its lifetime ends. You are trying to return a closure that holds a reference to subscriber, but subscriber will already be gone when that closure is called. `self` can go out of scope before it gets called too.

This is likely an anti-pattern. What is the purpose of the returned closure? Is it a sort of "undo action" (since it calls `remove`)? If so, I would just set up another function called `unsubscribe` that takes a `Subscriber`.